# Rotate Animation - Speedometer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to simulate a speedometer with to images (the speedometer and a pointer):

[image]

But when I rotate it to 90º, the result is this:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 90, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
    rotate.setDuration(5000);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    mSpeedometerPointerImage.startAnimation(rotate);
```

What should I do?

**EDIT**

[RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html)

[RELATIVE_TO_SELF](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#RELATIVE_TO_SELF)

**EDIT 2**

With only two args:

[image]

Comment: I've never used this class, but suspect its soemthing about the origin point and the RELATIVE_TO_SELF option... Are there other options? Can you include a link to the particular API in the OP ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt - Done.

Comment: Ok, so you are using the method signature that is providing the pivot points... what happens if you just pass the first two args ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt - I updated the OP.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. It was just a quick thought, but will have to wait for someone who's used the API before to chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your image in an image editor and pinpoint the exact point where you want the image to rotate around, ie: the place that stays put. Now note the x,y coordinates of that spot. Now the 4th parameter should be a float which, when multiplied by the image's width, will give you the x coordinate you need to define that point, and the 6th parameter should be the same multiplier for the y coordinate when multiplied by the height of the image. Just looking at it (and not knowing if there are transparencies etc.) it appears to me that the numbers will be somewhere around 0.8 (x) and 0.5 (y). Hope this helps.